# Is it possible for std::pair to return four values?

Tags: c++, methods, std, std-pair

In an assignment i was given a method that looks like this

```
std::pair<double, double> operator()(const Eigen::VectorXd &vec,
                                     int index) const {
    return (*this)(vec[index - 1], vec[index], vec[index + 1], vec[index + 2]);
}
```

I am a little bit confused on the return type of the method. Shouldn't it be a std::pair<double*, double*>?
Moreover, how can I deal with tying the returned values? Could something like

```
 std::tie(v1,v2,v3,v4)=reconstruction(vector,index);
```

work?

Comment: I'm guessing `this` has another `operator ()` which converts 4 doubles into a pair? It's difficult to help further without a [mre] and some indication of what the code is supposed to do

Comment: No a pair cannot contain 4 values. And no it should not be double*. You could return a std::array<double,4> or define your own struct with 4 values.

Comment: The return value is the result from callng a `std::pair<double, double> operator()(double, double, double, double)` member.

Comment: @PepijnKramer just use `std::tuple` for that instead of `std::array`